# Use of strdup in C. What is going wrong here

Tags: c

I am trying to compile below C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


char *argv[] = {"v1.0", "v2.0", "v3.0"};

int main(void)
{
    char *VER_LIST[] = {0};
    int i;

    /*for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        VER_LIST[i] = strdup(argv[i]);
    }   
    VER_LIST[i] = NULL;*/

    VER_LIST[0] = strdup(argv[0]);
    VER_LIST[1] = strdup(argv[1]);
    VER_LIST[2] = strdup(argv[2]);
    VER_LIST[3] = NULL;

    printf("%s", VER_LIST[2]);
    return 0;

}
```

It shows the correct output as v3.0, But if I comment this portion of code

```
VER_LIST[0] = strdup(argv[0]);
VER_LIST[1] = strdup(argv[1]);
VER_LIST[2] = strdup(argv[2]);
VER_LIST[3] = NULL;
```

and use `for` loop instead it is showing me the wrong result. Why am I getting the wrong result using the for loop instead? please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The array `char *VER_LIST[] = {0};` has only one element and you must not write anything to `VER_LIST[1]` and above, or you will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Allocate enough space first like `char *VER_LIST[4] = {0};`.

Comment: Yes. It worked!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

When the number in an array is not specified explicitly in its declaration then it is calculated according to the number of initializers used to initialize the array. Thus this declaration

```
char *VER_LIST[] = {0};
```

declares array `VER_LIST` as having one element.

You should define the array at least as having as many elements as the array argv has plus one for the last element that will be set to NULL.

for example

```
char *VER_LIST[sizeof( argv ) / sizeof( *argv ) + 1] = {0};
```

Also you need to free the memory allocated by each call of `strdup`